# SIGCHLD not delivered when a process exits

Tags: bash, bash-trap

I need to detect when one of my background processes exits. Hence, I installed a trap. `run_gui` and `run_ai1` are simple `exec` functions.

```
run_gui & gui_pid=$!
run_ai1 & ai1_pid=$!
trap 'echo foo' SIGCHLD
while true; do
    echo "Started the loop"
    while true; do
        read -u $ai1_outfd line || echo "Nothing read"
        if [[ $line ]]; then
            : # Handle this
        fi
    done
    while true; do
        read -u $gui_outfd line || echo "nothing read"
        if [[ $line ]]; then
            : # Handle this
        fi
    done
done
```

When I close the GUI, nothing happens. The `echo foo` command is executed only if I press ctrl+c.

Why do I miss the `SIGCHLD`?

Comment: This doesn't change anything. Does it matter that the `read` is waiting for some input...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Non-interactive shells don't enable job control by default.  See if
>   putting 'set -o monitor' at the beginning of the script produces the
>   results you want.

Source: [Chet Ramey](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2001-04/msg00065.html), GNU Bash's maintainer

Comment: My shabang is `#!/bin/bash -m`. So this shouldn't be the case

Comment: I suggest to test it.

Comment: The result is exactly the same.

Comment: This simple example works with GNU bash 4.2.8: `set -o monitor; trap 'echo hello' SIGCHLD; sleep 3 &`

Comment: After commenting out the `read` line, the problems seems gone away. It seems that `read` is blocking everything, the trap included. I read from a fd initialized as read-write in the main script and given to the `run_gui` internals